# How to determine a socket is shutdown() by another thread?

Tags: c, sockets

Is there a efficient way to determine a socket is `shutdown()` by another thread?

Comment: You can flag some global variable and check the socket status with it.  You, know, both threads run in the same program :)  It has no overhead at all, as it doesn't require any system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way at all, but if you have this kind of problem and you think you have to resort to system calls for your threads to tell each other what they are doing you have a much bigger problem at the design level.